# mongoDb Atlas connection time out error in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services

Getting this mongoDb atlas connection error please help me

(node:8071) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoNetworkError: connection 3 to prod-mdb-webapp-00-shard-00-01-e3fnj.mongodb.net:27017 closed

(node:8071) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: i mam getting this error in mongoDb node,js

Comment: and did you try to google your error first?

Comment: You probably shouldn't post your real db server names here. Might attract unwanted attention.

Answer (score 0):

In the code where you are connecting to the database, pull it out and wrap it in a `try{ ...your code } catch (e){ console.error(e) }` to see what the actual error is.

If I had to guess, I would say you are either not using the correct connection string, or you need to whitelist the IP address of your server in the MongoDB Atlas security settings for your cluster